# Какую самую позднюю версию фреймверка можно поставить на XP

Tags: .net

Какую самую позднюю версию .net framework можно поставить на Windows XP?

[Тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8z6watww%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) говорится что 4.5.1 можно

Comment: 4.0. for windows xp.

Answer (score 4):

- Windows XP - The .NET Framework 4
- Windows Vista SP2 - The .NET Framework 4, The .NET Framework 4.5.1...

Answer (score 2):

4.0 и ее минорные обновления (4.0.1-4.0.3). .NET Framework 4.5+ уже требует минимум Windows 7.

Comment: Отредактировал.

Comment: @SmitJohnth прочитайте внимательно информацию по ссылке, а именно табличку Supported client operating systems: Windows XP -- The .NET Framework 4.

Comment: Тьху, перепутал Vista SP2 с XP SP2.